# Find number of clusters in DBLP dataset

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to find the number of clusters in DBLP V11 dataset using field of study.

I've tried using doc2vec pretrained and average on word2vec pretrained and clustering the results using DBSCAN, hierarchical clustering and get the number of clusters using elbow method, silhouette method and gap statistics.

I get one or two clusters from this because all the articles are computer science related, but I need to find out the number of subfields from computer science.

Answer (score 0):

There is not "the" number of clusters in such data.

Instead, many answers are correct. Or none.

Is machine learning part of artificial intelligence? Is deep learning a separate topic? And data science? how is data science different from statistics? Doesn't statistics have lots of subtopics? What about big data, and how does it relate to data science? Isn't data mining the same as data science? Humans won't all agree on all of these topics either.